# How to calculate the expiration date 3 months before will be expire

Tags: mysql, vb.net

I need help how to get 3 months before expiration date alert. I used mysql.

```vb
Try
    Call connection()
    cmd.CommandText = "select * from medicine where expiry_date < date_sub(now(), interval 3 month)"
    dr = cmd.ExecuteReader
    count = 0
    While dr.Read
        count = count + 1
    End While
    If count = 1 Then
        pop.Image = Image.FromFile("E:\asasda.png")
        pop.TitleText = "Notification Alert!!!"
        pop.ContentText = "Medicine at Risk"
        pop.AnimationDuration = 3000
        pop.Popup()
    Else
        pop.Image = Image.FromFile("E:\asasda.png")
        pop.TitleText = "Notification Alert!!!"
        pop.ContentText = "No items for risk"
        pop.AnimationDuration = 3000
        pop.Popup()
    End If
Catch ex As Exception

End Try
```

Comment: Looks like you have made a reasonable attempt. What exactly is the issue you're having?

Comment: `If count = 1 Then` makes it say `"No items for risk"` unless there is *exactly* one item. Was that your intention?

Answer (score 1):

I commented our `Call Connection()`. It is best to keep your connections local so you can be sure they are closed and disposed.
A `Using...End Using` block will accomplish this even it there is an error. Also I don't see where you associated a connection to your command. The call keyword is not necessary in this case. I assume that Connection() returns a connection but your did not provide a variable to hold the connection.

Pass the `Select` statement and the connection directly to the constructor of the command.

You have consumed all the data you returned in the While loop. If you only only need the Count then ask for the `Count` and use `.ExecuteScalar`.

I don't see the point of the If because the if portion is identical to the else portion.

An empty Catch just swallows errors. Bad idea.

```vb
Private Sub OPCode()
    Dim CountReturned As Integer
    Try
        'Call Connection()
        Using cn As New MySqlConnection("Your connection string")
            Using cmd As New MySqlCommand("select Count(*) from medicine where expiry_date < date_sub(now(), interval 3 month);", cn)
                cn.Open()
                CountReturned = CInt(cmd.ExecuteScalar)
            End Using
        End Using
        If CountReturned = 1 Then
            pop.Image = Image.FromFile("E:\asasda.png")
            pop.TitleText = "Notification Alert!!!"
            pop.ContentText = "Medicine at Risk"
            pop.AnimationDuration = 3000
            pop.Popup()
        Else
            pop.Image = Image.FromFile("E:\asasda.png")
            pop.TitleText = "Notification Alert!!!"
            pop.ContentText = "No items for risk"
            pop.AnimationDuration = 3000
            pop.Popup()
        End If
    Catch ex As Exception
        MessageBox.Show(ex.Message)
    End Try
End Sub
```

If you cannot get the MySql `data_sub` working then use vb and parameters.

```vb
Using cmd As New MySqlCommand("select Count(*) from medicine where expiry_date < @Minus3Months;", cn)
    cmd.Parameters.Add("@Minus3Months", MySqlDbType.DateTime).Value = Now.AddMonths(-3)
```

Comment: As a note (for the OP), since there's just one value that is different in the `If` condition selector. It could all be reduce to: `pop.ContentText = If(CountReturned = 1, "Medicine at Risk", "No items for risk")`.

Comment: thank you @Mary .. i appreciate ur answer but still not working.. maybe my database query is wrong.. i used text type instead of date type for the date to save the expiry date into database

Answer (score 0):

```
cmd.CommandText = "select * from medicine where expiry_date < @threeMonthsAgo"
cmd.parameters.add("@threeMonthsAgo", variableWithYourDate)
```

You can pass in a value from VB using parameters.